# Distributional Derivative of a Piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, distribution-theory

> Use the definition of the distributional derivative to find the first-order derivative (in the distributional sense) of the function
>         \begin{align*}
>         h(x) = \left\{
>                 \begin{array}{lllll}
>                     0, & \quad x < -2\\
>                     2, & \quad -2 \leq x \leq -1\\
>                     0, & \quad -1 < x < 1\\
>                     1, & \quad 1 \leq x \leq 2\\
>                     0, & \quad x > 2
>                 \end{array}
>             \right.
>   \end{align*}

I assume here that i would have to split the integral into multiple parts and then solve it, but not sure how to proceed.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int h \phi '=2\phi (-1)-2\phi (-2)+\phi (2)-\phi (1)$ and hence $h'=-2\delta_{-1}+2\delta_{-2}-\delta_2+\delta_1$.